# MVC Bundle change CSS content to "?"

Tags: css, model-view-controller, bundle

While I'm trying bundling Slick CSS (http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/) which use his font. After bundling the CSS file, I can see the font file is loaded to client, but the content in CSS changed somehow to "?". I have tried to add `@charset 'UTF-8';` to CSS but it doesn't fix the problem.

I suspect that it is an encoding problem...

Comment: What version of MVC you are talking about? ASP.NET MVC ? If so which version...?